# Selecting just one row that has max datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, row, max

```
SELECT     v.DoorNo,v.NewDoorNo, v.GarageName, c.VersionDate, v.OperatorName as Operator, v.OperatorId, c.DeviceId, c.VehicleId, c.ProgramVersionNo, 
                  c.ParameterFileVersionNo, c.TariffFileVersionNo, c.BlaclistFileVersionNo, c.LineNoFileVersionNo, c.ScreenProgramVersion, 
                  c.SoapProgramVersiyon
FROM         dbo.vValidator AS v RIGHT JOIN
                  dbo.CDeviceVersion AS c  with(nolock) ON (v.DoorNo = c.DoorNo
                                or v.NewDoorNo=c.DoorNo
                                                          where v.NewDoorNo='O1211'
```

This query returns 2 rows, but I want to select just one row that has maximum versionDate. How can I select it?

Comment: When I added "or statement", it gives me two rows, but I delete "or statement" it give me one row.

Comment: are the other fields the same in your result set (when you get 2 rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT  TOP (1) v.DoorNo,v.NewDoorNo, v.GarageName, c.VersionDate, v.OperatorName as Operator, v.OperatorId, c.DeviceId, c.VehicleId, c.ProgramVersionNo, 
                  c.ParameterFileVersionNo, c.TariffFileVersionNo, c.BlaclistFileVersionNo, c.LineNoFileVersionNo, c.ScreenProgramVersion, 
                  c.SoapProgramVersiyon
FROM         dbo.vValidator AS v RIGHT JOIN
                  dbo.CDeviceVersion AS c  with(nolock) ON (v.DoorNo = c.DoorNo
                                or v.NewDoorNo=c.DoorNo)
                                                          where v.NewDoorNo='O1211'
 ORDER BY c.VersionDate
```

Comment: No, tsql does not accept limit statement. It is not working properly.

Comment: @mtinyavuz I believe that is the syntax. It's been ages though.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what you said, I use top 1 and order by c.VersionDate desc. I am surprised how I missed it.

Comment: Adding "desc" to order by statement will give the appropriate result. Thanks for your helping.